# How to display actual window size (width and height) automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple code, which by clicking shows the actual size of window (width and height) but I want to do this without clicking, for example when I change the size of window i want to changed the size automatically and displayed.
thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">show the window size</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + w + "<br>Height: " + h;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
window.addEventListener('resize',myFunction)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rk57hkak/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
window.onresize = myFunction;
```

Comment: hi, it works but it needs refresh the page, I need automatically change.

Comment: So just to be sure: You want to reload the page and run this function when the screen size changes?  This seems like a bad idea, but if you really want it I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

just add following function for this

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    myFunction();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery in this post, I'm going to assume you use it in your page.

Ideally, you don't want to fire your function every time the window resize event is fired, but after the resize completes. This involves the use of a debounce function...

There are multiple implementations out there in the world (for example, [the debounce from underscore.js](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)) but here's a simple implementation that should do the trick:

```
var resizeTimer;
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {    
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {    
    myFunction(); // call your function             
  }, 250); // in this case 250 milliseconds between events is required
})
.resize(); // call the resize event on page load to get your initial values
```